# grunt-contrib-watch with debug and release targets

Tags: gruntjs

With for instance the `concat` plugin, we can setup a debug and a release target in our Gruntfile.js:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  concat: {
    debug: {
    },
    release: {
    },
  }
```

is it possible to have multiple configurations for the [grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) plugin?

When doing this:

```
watch: {
  debug: {
    options: {
      livereload: true,
      nospawn: true
    },
    copy: {
      files: ['js/app/**/*.js', 'js-amd/**/*.js'],
      tasks: ['copy']
    }
```

I get an error saying `verifying property watch.debug.files exists in config`.

This does not work either:

```
watch: {
   debug: {
      options: {
        livereload: true,
        nospawn: true
      },
      files: ['js/app/**/*.js', 'js-amd/**/*.js'],
      tasks: ['copy'],

      files: ['jade/**/*.jade'],
      tasks: ['jade:devmock']
```

...since I cannot have two `files`-arrays or two `tasks`-arrays. (It ignores all but the first `files/tasks`-pair)

Is there some other way of achieving what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The configuration is a bit more flat.

```
  watch: {
    debug: {
      files: ['js/app/**/*.js', 'js-amd/**/*.js'],
      tasks: ['copy'],
      options: {
        livereload: true,
        nospawn: true
      }
    }
  }
```

You will find more examples here: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch

Comment: sorry, I've already tried this. It works if you only have one set of files and one set of tasks. See edited question for what happens if you have more

Comment: I got a new answer, is that what you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you want two sets of files, you will need a new set of config

```
watch: {
    debug: {
      files: ['js/app/**/*.js', 'js-amd/**/*.js'],
      tasks: ['copy'],
      options: {
        livereload: true,
        nospawn: true
      }
    },
    other-debug: {
      files: ['js/app/**/*.js', 'js-amd/**/*.js'],
      tasks: ['copy'],
      options: {
        livereload: true,
        nospawn: true
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution I've used is to define multiple watch targets and rename the watch task like so:

```
watch: {
    scripts: {
        files: ['js/**/*.js'],
        tasks: ['concat', 'uglify'],
        options: {
            spawn: false
        }
    }
},

// Don't uglify in dev task
watchdev: {
    scripts: {
        files: ['js/**/*.js'],
        tasks: ['concat'],
        options: {
            spawn: false
        }
    }
}

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
// Rename watch to watchdev and load it again
grunt.renameTask('watch', 'watchdev');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
grunt.registerTask('dev', ['watchdev']);
```